# Intent created but not opening the page for me

Tags: android, url, browser, android-intent

activity_main.xml

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/ButtonUrl"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/RenderBox_button">
</Button>
```

IntentTest.java

```
package com.example.test;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class IntentTest extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button buttonUrl = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonUrl);

    buttonUrl.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Uri uri=Uri.parse("http://www.google.com.tw");
            Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    }
}
```

When I run it, no error message whatsoever (on Eclipse), but when i click on the button, nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should setup the Intent like this:

```
String url = "http://www.google.com.tw";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: It works fine with me!! Your problem is something other than the intent.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, In addition for your information Here's the [documentation of Intent.ACTION_VIEW.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW)

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```